# Cannot Open table from SQL Server 2008 on SSMS 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I am using SSMS 2005 on my local workstation and have not yet installed SSMS2008 on it. When I connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance and try to "open" a table from SSMS2005 I cannot open. Instead I get an error (popup) that says:

> Unspecified Error
>     (MS Visual
>   Database Tools)

I have tried this on 2 SQL Server 2008 Instances, I have tried creating a database from scratch. The same problem exists for other users in my office. I have latest version of SSMS2005.

Perhaps this is not supported?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance using SQL Management Studio version 2005(SSMS 2005)... this is not allowed.

Instead, download Management Studio version 2008 (SSMS 2008) and you should be able to connect to your SQL Server 2008 instance without any problems.

SSMS 2008 Express:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

[Can I use SQL Server Management Studio 2005 for 2008 DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103/can-i-use-sql-server-management-studio-2005-for-2008-db)

> UPDATE: You can use Cumulative update
>   package 5 for SQL Server 2005 Service
>   Pack 2 to connect to 2008.
>
> FIX: 50002151 946127
>   (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946127/)
>   FIX: You may experience problems when
>   you use SQL Server Management Studio
>   in SQL Server 2005 to connect to an
>   instance of SQL Server 2008